# Element in First Index Doesn't Behave as the Rest

Tags: c, string

so I'm trying to do a very simple task. I need to write a function that gets an empty array of strings and its size and initialize it (for example "names={"dani", "gabi", "bobi"}, names is array of size 3 and each one hold a string that the user inputs). So first the user needs to put the size then I allocate the array and then I trying to get strings for the array each one for different address.

Now for some reason it works great for the rest of the array except for the one in the first index (arr[0]). I understand that because the "ENTER" is a char it gets it for the first string (when the user inputs the size)

But I don't want it to be like this and I'm trying to fix it for hours and I'm hopeless

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS#define SIZE 21
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


enum { FAIL = 0, SUCCESS = 1 };


int init_arr(char ***arr, int *size);


int main()
{
    int i, sizes = 0;
    char **course = NULL;


    init_arr(&course, &sizes);


    for (i = 0; i< sizes; i++)
        puts(course[i]);


    free(course);
    return 0;
}


int init_arr(char ***arr, int *size)
{
    int i;
    char* c;


    printf("Enter the Number of--->:");
    scanf("%d", size);


    *arr = (char**)malloc((*size) * sizeof(char*));
    if ((*arr) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return FAIL;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < (*size); i++)
    {
        c = (char*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
        if (c == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error");
            return FAIL;
        }
        printf("Enter Name %d-->:", i);

        fgets(c, SIZE, stdin);


        (*arr)[i] = c;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: take a dummy character  variable  and read it just after you read `size`, in this way the newline will be read in that dummy character variable.

Comment: `scanf("%d", size);` will leave a `newline` in the input buffer, so the first use of `fgets` will read an empty string. Best not to mix the methods.

Comment: i sorry i dident understand what you said can you explain it?

Comment: I guess I was repeating what the question says. Many ways to get round it, one way is to do a dummy read with `fgets` before the loop and throw it away.

Comment: i still dont understand how to fix it can you give an exemple?

Comment: Look take `char dummy` place `scanf("%c",&dummy)` , just after `scanf("%d",size)` in your code.

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga  Moreover, when you are asking/ telling something to some user through comments then use @{username} to notify him. As i did in this comment.

Comment: You *might* find other problems ... the `***` coding is not generally advised.

Comment: WTF guys you are geinus!!!!!

Comment: im trying to fix it for hours and you did it in seconeds i love you guys!!

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga Again ;)

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS thanks man !!

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you mean by problems? its work greatly and this is whats the task tell us to do...

Comment: Well done then. I was just commenting that using three stars is not usually a sign of a 3-star programmer.

Comment: What @WeatherVane means is that using a tripple-pointer `***` in C is (almost) always a signal of wrong design. He is right.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar();` will do the work:

```
printf("Enter the Number of--->:");
scanf("%d", size);
getchar(); // to read newline character
```

Comment: holy crap i cant belive its work and so simple im so noob thanks